# AADSTS65005 - Consent validation failed

Tags: rest, azure, outlook

This might not be the right forum, but i have registered my application in the 'Application Registration Portal' : https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList

I have the client id/app id & the client secret, and previously this was working using the following account : admin@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com, the 'Consent Request Pops-up' and i am able to give consent.

However, recently i am trying via another account, i.e. user3@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com, this redirects to my registered URL without the 'Consent screen'.

Below is the error message returned,

error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS65005%3a+Consent+validation+failed%3a%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+be71ab23-b45c-47a9-8932-50a24ce86505%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a49121b9-5bc2-4bd3-934d-551eaa68261b%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2015-10-26+08%3a28%3a02Z

Any hints would be great!